# Problems converting vertical list to horizontal in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have problem with CSS trying to make my list from vertical to horizontal. I tried removing `display:block` and adding `display:inline` but it didn't work. Also tried to remove width restrictions.

Here is the list in HTML. It is vertical at the moment. How can I get it to show as horizontal?

```css
.nav-container {
  width: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 1px black;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(#292929, #242424);
}

a {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #bbb;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 25%;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.active a {
  color: #B93632;
  border-left: 5px solid #B93632;
  background-color: #1B1B1B;
  outline: 0;
}

li:not(.active):hover a {
  color: #eee;
  border-left: 5px solid #FCFCFC;
  background-color: #1B1B1B;
}

span[class ^="icon"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .text {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-container,
  a {
    width: 70px;
  }
  a:hover {
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px black;
  }
  a:hover .text {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 30%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .nav-container,
  a {
    width: 50px;
  }
  span[class ^="icon"] {
    left: 8px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon-home"></span>
        <span class="text">github</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon-user"></span>
        <span class="text">front page</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <span class="text">video</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `float:left;` them.  Or right, if you prefer.  then you can add padding to add spacing.

Comment: `display: inline` for both the `li` and the `a` tags, and remove the `width` set for both `a` and `.nav-container`... Some styles got broken, but here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtr_webdev/8kufmh9y/)

Comment: Got it almost working with this float:left. Now they just overlap each other a bit. Could I somehow force them just be side by side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox is a display type very well-suited to this problem.  You can learn more about it at [css-tricks.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Your problem can be solved by applying a display:flex property to the ul and a flex-flow:row nowrap; property to the li

Comment: It might be helpful to create a working example using the OP's existing code.

Comment: [img](https://i.imgur.com/ERQ5F6k.png) got it working somewhat now. Need to make them same size now though. Also need change the borders right.